# Kony Visualizer - Ctrl + space doesn't list out header and footers

Tags: temenos-quantum

Trying to access header or its widgets using code or API, Is there any existing APIs or single line code to access headers and footers ?. I am unable to see the list of options while doing a ctrl + space in kony visualizer editor, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
kony.application.getCurrentForm().headers[0]
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11061374)

Comment: That is the code to access the header and its widgets... that was the answer to the question.

Comment: I have seen that only child elements can be accessed and not headers and footer names.